Given a system of polynomials over $F_2$, find the element which has the maximum number of solutions.
Given a system of polynomials over a binary polynomial ring $F_2[x_1,...,x_n]$ $$S = [f_1(x_1,...,x_n),f_2(x_1,...,x_n),...,f_n(x_1,...,x_n)] $$.
I want to find the element $y \in F_2^n$ which has the maximum number of solutions $S(x_1,...,x_n) = y$
I am looking for any kind references about this sort inverse equations solving where I am not looking for a solution, but the element which has the most solution.
